# find the volume of the half-cone $\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}<z<1,\ x>0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to find the volume of the half-cone $$\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}<z<1,\ x>0$$

I have found the range of $x$ and $z$ which are $0<x<1, \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}<z<1$, but I cannot figure out what the range of $y$ is. Could anyone help me with that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of the volume with the horizontal plane defined by $z$ (with $0<z<1$) is the half disc $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<z, x>0$, of surface $\pi z^2/2$.

Hence the desired volume is $$\int_0^1{\pi z^2\over2}d z=\pi/6$$

Comment: Don't forget it's a half-cone. The base isn't a disc, it's a semi-circle/half-disc.

Comment: You caught it just as I commented.

Comment: @Axoren. Yes; thanks for noticing anyway. Fixed this, and the next issue about legibility, within the 5 minute allowance.

Comment: The edit is too small to submit, but you should use double-dollar signs to make the integral large enough to read.